# Steam on WSL Won't Launch

Tags: steam, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install Steam via Ubuntu on WSL. I followed [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469793/install-linux-steam-on-wsl2-through-windows).

When I try to run Steam, it opens and immediately closes the update box Steam usually opens before launching the main window. Here is the output:

```
steam.sh[408]: Running Steam on ubuntu 22.04 64-bit
steam.sh[408]: STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
setup.sh[478]: Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
steam.sh[408]: Steam client's requirements are satisfied
[2024-01-04 11:48:14] Startup - updater built Dec  8 2023 00:32:59
[2024-01-04 11:48:14] Startup - Steam Client launched with: '/home/jrgra/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam' '-nominidumps' '-nobreakpad'
01/04 11:48:14 Init: Installing breakpad exception handler for 
appid(steam)/version(1702079146)/tid(531)
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2024-01-04 11:48:14] Loading cached metrics from disk (/home/jrgra/.steam/debian-installation/package/steam_client_metrics.bin)
[2024-01-04 11:48:14] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2024-01-04 11:48:14] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2024-01-04 11:48:14] 1. https://cdn.steamstatic.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
[2024-01-04 11:48:14] Checking for update on startup
[2024-01-04 11:48:14] Checking for available updates...
[2024-01-04 11:48:14] Downloading manifest: https://cdn.steamstatic.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2024-01-04 11:48:14] Manifest download: send request
[2024-01-04 11:48:14] Manifest download: waiting for download to finish
[2024-01-04 11:48:14] Manifest download: finished
[2024-01-04 11:48:14] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1702079146, installed version 1702079146, existing pending version 0
[2024-01-04 11:48:14] Nothing to do
[2024-01-04 11:48:14] Verifying installation...
[2024-01-04 11:48:14] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2024-01-04 11:48:15] Verification complete

Steam logging initialized: directory: /home/jrgra/.steam/debian-installation/logs

XRRGetOutputInfo Workaround: initialized with override: 0 real: 0xf640c9c0
XRRGetCrtcInfo Workaround: initialized with override: 0 real: 0xf640b1f0
steamwebhelper.sh[771]: Runtime for steamwebhelper: defaulting to /home/jrgra/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_64/steam-runtime-heavy
steamwebhelper.sh[771]: glibc >= 2.34, partially disabling sandbox until CEF supports clone3()
CAppInfoCacheReadFromDiskThread took 0 milliseconds to initialize
Segmentation fault

Steam Runtime Launch Service: starting steam-runtime-launcher-service
Steam Runtime Launch Service: steam-runtime-launcher-service is running pid 937
bus_name=com.steampowered.PressureVessel.LaunchAlongsideSteam
steamwebhelper.sh[1166]: Runtime for steamwebhelper: defaulting to 
/home/jrgra/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_64/steam-runtime-heavy
steamwebhelper.sh[1166]: glibc >= 2.34, partially disabling sandbox until CEF supports 
clone3()
```

The last two lines will repeat over and over and it never opens. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use Steam for Windows?  Is there a *reason* you need Steam to run on WSL?  (WSL requires Windows anyways)

Comment: Yes, I am testing DXVK as well as some things that Linux Steam may do differently regarding shader compilation. It's mostly a learning exercise.

Comment: I would not be using WSL to test DXVK that Linux Steam does differently.  It may run "Linux" components of Steam, but it is still a Windows computer.  If you want to test the LInux side, I would install Linux on a second hard drive and boot to that and then use *that* to set everything up

Comment: I appreciate what you're trying to do, but I am explicitly trying to test how it behaves in Windows via WSL. I've seen claims of people using WSL to leverage the benefits of forced shader caching and I am trying to test if it actually behaves differently. Running Linux natively would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Been seeing the same thing